# .net 4.0 c# : Pausing/Resuming parallel running threads from threadpool temporarily?

Tags: c#-4.0

I could setup a multi-threaded environment using the .net ThreadPool and I do get a significant performance benefit. This runs in the background of my application.

Now when a new task is requested by the user, I want it to get maximum CPU resources to maximize performance. Hence I would like to temporarily pause all the threads that I began (via the ThreadPool.Queueuserworkitem method) and then resume once the new task, requested by the user in foreground, is completed.

There could be several solutions to my problem:

a. Starting lesser background threads so that any new user request gets some share of the CPU resources. (but I loose the performance gain I had :( )

b. Set higher priority for the thread for a new user requested task. (not sure if this works?)

c. Suspending/resuming the ThreadPool threads I began. But suspending / resuming / interrupting threads is highly discouraged. Moreover, this could get tricky and error prone.

Any other ideas?

Note: when the user makes a request, performing the task would normally not take more than 300ms. However, when I start ThreadPool threads in background, it now takes about 3 seconds to complete (10 times worse)! I am OK if it takes 500-800ms though. All background threads complete in about 8 seconds (and I am OK if they take 1-2 seconds more). Hence, I am trying out option ( a ) for now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just use a Thread instead of the thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

Be noted that Thread scheduling is done by CPU and hence cannot be directed from within a program. Only thing that can be done is setting ThreadPriority (that too on new Threads, not on ThreadPool threads). Check section [Limitations of Using the Thread Pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647332.aspx)

As your requirement is to suspend all background threads while executing a new task, what you can do is to create a class level flag.

Now you can put checkpoints in methods to be executed in Background task. At the checkpoints, check the class level flag, if it is set, call Thread.Sleep, which should (NOT MUST) trigger thread context switch by OS/CPU thread scheduler.

Putting checkpoints in methods (to be executed by ThreadPool) is analogous to putting [checkpoints for cancellation support in background worker.](http://www.dotneat.net/2009/02/10/BackgroundworkerExample.aspx)